# substitution algorithm

Tags: string, encryption, cryptography, substring, substitution

How to perform substitution encryption algorithm in ASP.NET using C# code ?

Please do provide me with sample code syntax....

Comment: Are you referring to a substitution cipher?  You could use [ROT13](http://www.dotnetperls.com/rot13).  I don't think the word "encryption" accurately applies to a substitution cipher incidentally.

Comment: Perfect answer for my question... Thanks Mark...

Comment: Note that I didn't actually test the code on that link (it was just the first google hit for "rot13 c#"). But it does "look" reasonable as long as you are only dealing with ASCII characters.

Comment: Of course this "encryption" isn't secure at all.

Comment: why don't it provide security?

Comment: @Codeln why is it not secured?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually ROT13 is a variant of [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) which idea is to shift letter of plain-text by N positions further in the alphabet. Neither ROT13 or Caesar cipher is secure. Why ?

Basically one can define encryption strength as amount of work one needs to do for breaking given encrypted text. So what we should do for breaking these ? :

- ROT13 -> we simply shift back each character by 13 positions in alphabet. (No security at all).
- Caesar cipher -> 
  `for N=1 to 26 do:`
      `shift each character by N positions back in the alphabet.`
      `If a lot of common English words (the, and, that,...) - encryption is cracked.` 
  So in Caesar case still 26 iterations for cracking encrypted text is so small number that we can safely claim that Caesar cipher has no security also. (But of course it is a bit better than ROT13).

If you want a bit more useful substitution cipher- then use [Vigenere cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher). Contrary to ROT13/Caesar ciphers - Vigenere cipher doesn't use FIXED alphabet in encryption operation. (It uses several alphabets by switching them in required order). That is why Vigenere is more secure than ROT13/Caesar. Still Vigenere is weak encryption and is comparable to [XOR encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher). Why Vigenere is weak ? Basically because it is vulnerable to [Frequency analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) (of course at first one needs to guess/find key length).
Here it is [vigenere C# code](http://www.cheesydoodle.com/?p=155) (along with Caesar/ROT13).

good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder encryptedBuilder = new Stringbuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++) {
    char e = getCharFor(key[i]); // this does substitution - implement this
    encryptedBuilder.Append(e);
}

string encryptedString = encryptedBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: The above code shows errors at "getCharFor" and "append" Hope problem lies at my side I am using VS2k5 .NET 2.0 Anyways thanks... :)

Comment: You have to define the `getCharFor` function yourself. That's where you do your substitution. And the `append` should be `Append` with a capital A. My bad (too much Java! :p)